# Magento 1.8 always redirect to store home page,

Tags: magento

I have a Magento 1.8 site running well for long time. But suddenly one day, without any change done, it always redirect to site homepage no matter accessing it from front end or from back end as admin login.  The redirection happen in a random time period when you click few pages, some time it happen immediately on next click, so you always see homepage. it happen to Both IE and firefox.

Before this problem appear what I did was just adding or modifying product only, no system setting/configuration change at all. Now, it is hard to login admin panel as it keep redirecting to homepage.

it seems issue related to session, but I don't know what cause the problem and how to find it and solve it. Also why Magento site suddenly have such behavior?
Any mater Please help.  Thank you in advance.

Update: It appears severely with IE, nowhere you can go except homepage, with Firefox, it appear randomly and allow going few click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after following a fix given in this link http://laksmono.com/2009/05/13/userscustomers-cannot-checkout-magento-cart/.  my site seems working now.

that is -- under System > Configurations > Web > session validation settings, set ‘no’ to everything except “Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT.” then remember to flash Magento cache.

it sounds like ISP applied some new technique some day to cause this problem....But can any one tell or explain how to understand these settings and why such setting can fix the problem?

Why I can visit many many other web sites including with account login and e-commerce sites without such problem at same time? The shame is I am using the same ISP and only Magento web giving me problem. This ISP is serving millions customers, no one receiving a notice from ISP requiring doing any thing... I mean if this is a common or necessary setting for all webs to work properly, why Magento leaves this to admin configuration which end up a big hole?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem occured due to cookie than try the below method can work for you.If you are not able to log in to your admin panel than check values for cookies in magento database. In phpmyadmin find table core_config_data, then fields with values : web/cookie/cookie_domain and web/cookie/cookie_path. They may be blank ni your case.

My solution was to set:

web/cookie/cookie_domain to my domain name

and

web/cookie/cookie_path to /.

Example:

your domain where you run magento is magento.local set:

web/cookie/cookie_path = magento.local

and

web/cookie/cookie_path = /

Try this, hope it will help.

Comment: These two setting were correctly set since day one and never change. as I said in post the web has been running for some time no problem...but thank you so much for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the core_config_data

```
web/secure/base_url
```

and

```
web/unsecure/base_url
```

are setup correctly. When you have one www. and one non-www. magento keeps redirecting.
For localhost cookiese use:

`web/cookie/cookie_path = "/"  (without quotes ofcourse)`

and

```
web/cookie/cookie_domain = ""  (without quotes ofcourse)
```